# Accessing the Django embedded server for development inside PyCharm by other hosts inside my local network?

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I'm working with PyCharm and I wonder if there's a way to make the Django embedded server accesible for the other hosts in my local network or I need to deploy my app on a dedicated web server such as Apache?

Now, I'm accessing my Django app like this in the browser:

```
http://localhost:8000/mypage/
```

and I want other users inside my local network to type:

```
http://my_private_ip:8000/mypage/
```

in their browsers and see the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run the server (which is Django's embedded server FWIW, not PyCharm's) under `http://my_private_ip:8000`:

```
 # ./manage.py help runserver
 Usage: manage.py runserver [options] [optional port number, or ipaddr:port]

 Starts a lightweight Web server for development.
 (...)

 # ./manage.py runserver my_private_ip:8000
```

Comment: Thank you bruno desthuilliers. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a Unix environment.

You need to ensure the server is listening not on the `lo` interface but on *all* interfaces (or at least the one used to connect to the LAN).

If you can customize the way PyCharm launches the server, use `0.0.0.0` as the host, as in:

```
 python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Your coworkers can then use your LAN IP address. If you don't know it, use `$ ip a`.